# Pandas add NA rows based on index

Tags: python, pandas

I've a pandas dataframe that looks something like this:

```
            Product_1  Product_2  Product_3  Product_4  Product_5
1492        1944         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         
1493        1944         NaN         NaN       16482        6185         
1494        1944       13208       20378       16482        6185         
1498        2146       13208       20378       16482        6694        
1503        2146       13973       20378       16552        6694
```

I wish to enter new rows 1495, 1496, 1497 and similarly 1499, 1500, 1501 and 1502 with NaN values in all columns. This seems to be a very simple job, just wondering if there is a built in pandas function to do such a thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [`.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html#pandas.DataFrame.reindex):

```
>>> df.reindex(range(1492, 1504))
      Product_1  Product_2  Product_3  Product_4  Product_5
1492       1944        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
1493       1944        NaN        NaN      16482       6185
1494       1944      13208      20378      16482       6185
1495        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
1496        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
1497        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
1498       2146      13208      20378      16482       6694
1499        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
1500        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
1501        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
1502        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
1503       2146      13973      20378      16552       6694
```

Comment: Oh, damn, why couldn't I find this method in the documentation, sounds like such a silly question now. Thanks nevertheless.

Comment: Instead of hard-coding, maybe relative values `df.reindex(range(min(df.index), max(df.index)))`

Comment: @PierreLafortune it should be `df.index.max() + 1`, because `range` does not include right end